# C# WinForm Concurrency with Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, thread-safety

I have a UI that occasionally interacts with a MSSQL DB. There is a heartbeat thread that inserts/updates data to the same DB within an **Invoke** statement.

**1)** Is my implementation a safeguard against DB data inconsistency/corruption?

**2)** Is **Invoke** the most efficient/simplest way of creating DB serialization between UI thread/heartbeat thread or are **locks** the way to go?

Comment: That depends on how you want your user to interact. There's nothing wrong with invoking the update on the db within a separate thread. Though is the user the one the initiates this db update? Could you give a little more info on the user workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think about BackgroundWorker. It is good abstraction of calling Invoke method, It handle most of cases.

Comment: Does RunWorkCompleted from the BackgroundWorker block the UI thread to stop concurrency issues? If so, I think this is a good alternative.